# custom validation Rule to set a particular string in javascript

Tags: jquery, custom-validators

There is an text field **id_number** and for the data to be entered in this field should satisfy the following conditions

1. The first 2 letters must be "MU" or "mu"
2. No spaces or special character will be allowed

If the value in **id_number** doesn't match the 2 above condition then **"Please enter valid ID e.g, MUXYZ001"** will be displayed.

For this I have written a short custom validation rule:

```
{literal}
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkId", function(value, element) {
var id_val = $("#id_number").val();
var string1=id_val.substr(0,2);
var badchars = /[<>$@&+()[\]{},` ]/;

if ( (string1=='mu') && (!(badchars.test(id_val)))){ 
               return false;
          }else{
              return true;
          }
}, "Please enter valid ID e.g, MUXYZ001");{/literal}
```

and the custom rule :

```
rules: {
         id_number: {checkId: true}
       }
```

but it's not working ..

Someone kindly fix it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use regex instead, see this sample snippet to get the idea:

```
{literal}
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkId", function(value, element) {
var id_val = $("#id_number").val(); 
       var reg= new RegExp("^mu\\d{2}\\D+$","i"); 
       if (reg.test(id_val)){ 
                   return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
}, "Please enter valid ID e.g, MUXYZ001");{/literal}
```

Comment: Thanks @roasted. But I want exact 2 digits after "MU" and then the string will be followed by characters. So I tried "^[mu]\\[0-9]{2}\\w+$" but It's not working.  So could you please correct the regx thing?

Comment: I assume by characters you means 'not numeric' so use this: var reg= new RegExp("^mu\\d{2}\\D+$","i");

Comment: No. It's just a sting that I have used for practice on regx.